# How can I put GCD objects into CF collection (CFArray, CFDictionary)?

Tags: cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, core-foundation

The deployment target is 10.6, therefore manual memory management is required.
The collection should take care of retaining/releasing GCD objects.

I believe custom callbacks for CFArray of CFDictionary would help, however I'm looking for a drop-in, well-tested solution

Comment: There's really not much to it. For an array, your `CFArrayRetainCallBack` would call `dispatch_retain()` and return the original object, and your `CFArrayReleaseCallBack` would call `dispatch_release()`. Do you have reason to believe that more is necessary than that obvious solution?

Comment: @KurtRevis If you provide an implementation, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callbacks and collection creation are straightforward:

```
static const void * dispatchObjectRetainCallBack(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value)
{
    if (value) {
        dispatch_retain(value);
    }
    return value;
}

static void dispatchObjectReleaseCallBack(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value)
{
    if (value) {
        dispatch_release(value);
    }
}

CFMutableArrayRef CreateDispatchHoldingArray()
{
    CFArrayCallBacks callBacks = {
        0,
        dispatchObjectRetainCallBack,
        dispatchObjectReleaseCallBack,
        NULL,
        NULL
    };
    return CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &callBacks);
}

CFMutableDictionaryRef CreateDispatchHoldingDictionary()
{
    CFDictionaryValueCallBacks valueCallBacks = {
        0,
        dispatchObjectRetainCallBack,
        dispatchObjectReleaseCallBack,
        NULL,
        NULL
    };
    return CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &valueCallBacks);
}
```

The slightly tricky part is getting the `dispatch_object_t`s in and out of the collections. You cannot simply cast a variable of type `dispatch_object_t` to a `void *`, because `dispatch_object_t` is a typedef of a union. The compiler gives an error:

```
Operand of type 'dispatch_object_t' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

You have to go through one of the union types inside the `dispatch_object_t`, like so:

```
void AddDispatchObjectToArray(CFMutableArrayRef array, dispatch_object_t obj)
{
    void* voidPtrObj = obj._do;
    CFArrayAppendValue(array, voidPtrObj);
}

dispatch_object_t GetDispatchObjectAtIndex(CFMutableArrayRef array, CFIndex index)
{
    dispatch_object_t result;
    result._do = (struct dispatch_object_s *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, index);
    return result;
}
```